# automatic reload of div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

instead of a whole page refresh after a certain time, i'd just like a specific div container to reload/refresh. is there any way to do this?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="quoteContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `jQuery.ajax`, parse what you server returns, take `div#wrapper` content from ajax response and put it into `div#wrapper`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the effect you desire with jQuery and Googles ajax api

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
   $('#load_latest_scores').load('latest_scores.html');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
<body>
<div id="load_latest_scores"> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this works, but initially when the page loads, the container is empty. how do i resolve that?

Comment: You could write a similar javascript function that pre-fills the div on page load

Answer (score 4):

If you had a page that served quotes, like `quote.html` for example, you could do this:

```
setInterval(refreshQuote, 10000); //every 10 seconds

function refreshQuote() {
  $("#quoteContainer").load("quote.html");
}
```

In this case the expected return from `quote.html` (or whatever source you have) it a simple string that is the quote, it will take this and replace the content of `<div id="quoteContainer"></div>` with it.

Answer (score 2):

i think that one aproach would be

```
<script>
function render (){
$('#mydiv').html("<b>new stuff</b>")
}
window.setInterval(render, 500);
</script>
```