# How to reload, a part of a webpage after a given time?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

What i want to do is, to show a message based on certain condition.
So, i will read the database after a given time continuously, and accordingly, show the message to the user. 
But i want the message, to be updated only on a part of the page(lets say a DIV).

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595005/automatic-reload-of-div-container

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

The below example will refresh a div with ID result with the content of another file every 5 seconds:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#result').load('test.html');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval if you want to make the request for content periodically and update the contents of your DIV with the AJAX response e.g.

```
setInterval(makeRequestAndPopulateDiv, "5000"); // 5 seconds
```

The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called.

If you are using a JS library you can update the DIV very easily e.g. in [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) you can use replace on your div e.g.

$('yourDiv').replace('your new content');

Answer (score 0):

You need a ajax solution if you want to load data from your database and show it on your currently loaded page without page loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="  JQUERY LIBRARY FILE PATH"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var init;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        init = window.setInterval('call()',5000);// 5000 is milisecond
    });

    function call(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'your server file name',
            type:'post',
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(msg){
                $('div#xyz').html(msg);// #xyz id of your div in which you want place result
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('Error in loading...');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting that my method is the best, but what I generally do to deal with dynamic stuff that needs access to the database is the following method :

**1- A server-side script that gets a message according to a given context, let's call it "contextmsg.php".**

```
<?php
$ctx = intval($_POST["ctx"]);
$msg = getMessageFromDatabase($ctx); // get the message according to $ctx number
echo $msg;
?>
```

**2- in your client-side page, with jquery :**

```
var DIV_ID = "div-message";
var INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;

setInterval(function() {
    updateMessage(currentContext)
}, INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS*1000);

function updateMessage(ctx) {
    _e(DIV_ID).innerHTML = getMessage(ctx);
}

function getMessage(ctx) {
    var msg = null;
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "contextmsg.php",
        data: {
            "ctx": ctx
        },
        success: function(data) {
            msg = data.responseText;
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return msg;
}

function _e(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Hope this helps :)