# Refresh Mysql Count without reloading page

Tags: php, mysql

How do i refresh count without having to load the page. I tried a couple of jQuery and Ajax but it is not working for me. i also tried this link  [automatic reload of div container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595005/automatic-reload-of-div-container) when a user submits a request it comes in as received 1 but when a user submits another request while the page is open it stays one and does not move to 2. Same with updating and completing.

```html
<tr>
  <td style="width: 125px"><a href="received.php" target="Frame">Received</a></td>
  <td style="width: 125px" align="center"><a href="received.php" target="Frame">

<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='received'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
  echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
}  
?></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By separating your view from your backend this can easily be done via AJAX:

some_php_file.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE status='received'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    echo $row['COUNT(*)'];  
}
```

your_view.html

```
<tr>
    <td style="width: 125px"><a href="received.php" target="Frame">Received</a></td>
    <td style="width: 125px" align="center">
        <a href="received.php" target="Frame">
            <span class="update_me_value"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

your_js.js

```
// wrap me in a loop setInterval or what not
$.ajax({
    type: METHOD GOES HERE
    //hit your php backend
    success: function(data) {
        $(".update_me_value").empty().append(data);
```

Comment: I will give this a try I didn't think of separating the view and the results

Answer (score 1):

Morissette is correct you will only be able to do this with AJAX. AJAX is designed just for calls such as these. The web is state less for the most part for when the server sends data to a client another call has to be made to the server to get updated information.

Another option but not really recommended would be to use an HTML frame that would just display the count value and then use javascript to keep refreshing the page.

Side note and not part of the question. If you are using INNODB try to avoid COUNT(*) as this will have to ignore the indexes. If your using MyISAM this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a javascript setInterval to call periodically a ajax request that gets numer of results/pages and update your pagination etc..

Another option you have is the use of sockets to notify at all connected users that a new page is available. It is more complex.

If you have paging there a better way to get the number of MySQL query results. You can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS()